# Find the same element in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

this is my code... When i enter more than 3 the same element of array the output also loop more than 3

for example:

Enter number of times: 5

Enter a Number:

1 , 2 ,3 , 1, 1

Same element: 1 , 1, 1 (it should be "1" only not "1 ,1, 1")

but if i enter

1 , 1 ,2 ,3 ,4

Same element: 1 (i think the bug is in the loop.. can someone help me .. im just a beginner... i hope you understand)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    

    int times, number;

    int max_count = 0;
    
    cout<<"Ente Number of Times: ";
    cin>>times;
    int arr[times]; 
    
    times = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cout<<"\n";
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < times ; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < times ; i++){
    
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < times ; j++)
        

            
                if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                cout<<"Same element: "<<arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!!, Can you show what you have tried, what you think we can write there ?

Comment: hey kenmark, I'd suggest you to have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Use a std::container (p.e. `std::vector<int>`) and then you should be able to find what you need at the link I posted

Comment: Is it possible that the repeating number is 2? (int arr[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2}) or that there are different repeating numbers (int arr[] = {1,, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3})?

Comment: my code is shown above'

Comment: If the same element appears m times, then with you algorithm it will be displayed m(m-1)/2 times. If you can, use a `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first element (`arr [0]`), that will be 1.  Scan the following elements, `arr [i]`, until you find another 1. That will happen when `i == 5`.  So the same element will be 1.